# How to add locale to security yaml?

Tags: php, symfony5

I need routes with `locale` to run without any authentication required. So far I have added  all the languages inside `access_control`

```
access_control:
    - { path: ^/v1/(en|de)/translation, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

This is working fine. But when I have more language, then I need to add here. Is there any better way to implement this ?

Something like use the locales added in `services.yaml`

```
parameters:
    locale: 'de'
    locales: ['de', 'en']
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create an regular expression what contemplee all the locales, if user tries to access with a non existent locale, symfony will return that the route doesn't exists.

```
{path:'^/v1/[a-z]{2}/translation', roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY]}
```

To manage locale lists, I have this on services.yaml:

```
app_locales: '%env(app_locales)%'
```

This will find the local list on your env file, in mi case .env.local

```
app_locales='de|en'
```

With that solution, you don't have to deploy code to add new locales, only you will have to edit the env file.

Tell me if that works for you.